# About estimating sopf(n)

Tags: number-theory

I have searched the web for an estimate of the function $\mathrm{sopf}(n)$, and I only saw estimates of its summatory function $$\sum_{n\le x}\mathrm{sopf}(n)$$ instead of the function $\mathrm{sopf}(n)$ itself. Is there an accurate asymptotic way of estimating the function $\mathrm{sopf}(n)$?

Comment: Do you mean this function? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofPrimeFactors.html

Comment: @lhf Yes, but just the sum of each prime factor once.

Comment: I think sopf(n) is going to be 2 for all powers of 2, and =n for all primes n, and somewhere between for other n. So maybe in a sense, there is not really a good estimation for just the function itself, am my intuition sensible?